# How to get count of all selected fields in a record?

Tags: custom-field

Let consider an object has 10 fields and one more field called CountField. If I enter a value for field1 and if i save it, Then the CountField value should be updated with 1. Same like that if I enter value for field1 and field2, Then the CountField field value should be updated with 2. Even if i enter a values for field1, field3, field9 and field5, then the CountField should be updated with 4 and vice versa. which means how many fields i entered values, the same value should be updated with CountField.[image]

I have tried alot. but i could not get any logic. Please provide some solution.

[image]

Note:The value of count field in image entered by me manually.

Comment: For this you need  to user `before update` trigger... Here check for `Trigger.OLD` and `Trigger.NEW` values if same then field not updated if different then field is updated so increment count value for `CountField`; That's it;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a formula field (type numeric):

e.g.

```
IF(ISBLANK(Title) , 0, 1) + IF(ISBLANK(Firstname) , 0, 1) + IF(ISBLANK(LastName) , 0, 1) + IF(ISBLANK(MobilePhone) , 0, 1) + IF(ISBLANK(Email) , 0, 1) + IF( ISPICKVAL(Industry , ""), 0, 1)
```

This is a numeric field (default value is 0).
For each field that is not empty, 1 is added to the zero. This is organized by the IF(  , , ) function. If blank, then 0 is added. If not blank, then 1 is added.

E.g. if Title and Firstname are filled and the rest is empty, the formula result will be (1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 =) 2

Comment: What if field already having value before update?

Comment: Then it would also count...

Comment: Can you explain what is 0,1 in IF(ISBLANK(Title) , 0, 1) and also all fields?@Guy
Thank you

Comment: After some update this count field value will increase the total number of fields count... then ... ???

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 this is a formula field so it is re-evaluated anytime the record is queried/shown on screen.

Comment: But you said that "Then it would also count..."?

Comment: I didn't say that :-) But I think the original question is about counting the non-blank fields and not counting the changes to the fields.

Comment: Yeah...!
My question is about counting the non-blank fields and not counting the changes to the fields

Comment: @Guy OP said that **how many fields i entered values, the same value should be updated with CountField.**

Comment: @itzmukeshy7
For Example, If i enter a value for field1 then countfield value should be 1. If i enter a value for field1 and field2 then countfield value should be 2. If i enter a value for field2, field9, field5 and field3 then countfield value should be 4 and vice versa.